# This Connect Wall has some troubles

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall

Divide these sixteen words into four groups based on something they have in common. You'll find that each of the four groups gives you a clue leading to something in particular. The words aren't in any particular order.

> **WELL, PACE, WITCH, WADE, CLOUD, PLANETS, TAR, FLUORINE, SCOPES, ANGER, EVIL, LIVES, HIP, HOOT, BROWN, RUGGED**

Once you've figured out the groups and the thing the wall is cluing, answer me this: **What is small and causes problems?**

*This puzzle is dedicated to @matt/@merrybot, with permission!*

Hint #1:

> The groups are cluing something to do with Matt's favorite media franchise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deus has found the groups already (go check out his answer) but if we rearrange the order they're in we get:

> D, S, 9, Trials.

which is a reference to

> the *Star Trek Deep Space Nine* episode *Trials and Tribble-ations*.

What're small and cause problems?

> Tribbles: alien furballs born pregnant; they reproduce very quickly.

Comment: (Title was also a reference to the TOS episode that introduced Tribbles, "The Trouble with Tribbles." :D)

Comment: ohhhh I didn't even notice that lol

Answer (score 4):

Group 1:

> The words RUGGED, ANGER, EVIL, and WELL can all have the letter D prepended to them to form new words. (DRUGGED, DANGER, DEVIL, DWELL.)

Group 2:

> The words PACE, TAR, HIP, and HOOT can all have the letter S put on both sides to make new words. (SPACES, STARS, SHIPS, SHOOTS.)

Group 3:

> The words WADE, SCOPES, BROWN, and WITCH are all famous trial participants. (Roe v. Wade, Tennessee v. Scopes, Brown v. Board of Education, and the Salem witch trials.)

Group 4:

> The words CLOUD, PLANETS, FLUORINE, and LIVES are all associated with the number 9.  ("Cloud nine", there were considered to be 9 planets until 2006, Fluorine is the 9th element, and cats are said to have 9 lives.)

One possible thing that the wall could be cluing is

> a HOLE? Both DHOLE and SHOLES are words (though neither is particularly common); golf courses have nine holes in each half; and there do seem to be many court cases involving someone with a name of Hole, though I can't find any notable ones. And of course, this answers the riddle - a small hole (in your clothing, for instance, or perhaps a submarine) can certainly cause problems!

Comment: Not that it really changes anything, but rot13: jul qvq lbh nqq F gb obgu fvqrf sbe tebhc gjb? Jbhyqa'g whfg nqqvat na F gb gur ortvaavat nyfb jbex?

Comment: @samm82 Yes, it would! When I saw the more specific connection, I used it to rule out at least one other entry, so I figured it might be the intended one.

Comment: Oh I see - rot13: Ohg vs lbh ehyrq bhg jvgpu orpnhfr "fjvgpuf" vfa'g n jbeq, gung qbrfa'g rkcynva jryy/fjryyf sebz tebhc bar

Comment: @samm82 Yes, it's not a rule that each group only has four words that fit it -- just that all of the groups together should have exactly one way to satisfy them. It's very possible that the looser version was the intended one. My choice was a guess, not a deduction.

Comment: These are the correct groups, but you're missing a key bit about the answer and what it is cluing! I'm not sure what more of a hint to give except to think about the letters and the number and what famous things they might be associated with.

Comment: I think probably rot13(Gevnyf naq Gevooyr-ngvbaf).

Comment: (note that that comment was posted _after_ Sciborg's hint was added to the question, whereas all Deusovi's earlier writing is _before_ that hint)